# What is this probability distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose we have a family $F_0,F_1,\dots$ of independent random variables which take the value $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ otherwise; let $\delta$ be a number between $0$ and $1$. Let

$X_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \delta^{n-k} F_k$.

I'm interested in the distribution of $X_n$. It seems straightforward enough to be known and have a name - does anybody know what it is?

Comment: In the formula you probably meant $F_k$ instead of $F_n$. Also, replacing $n-k$ with $k$ seems more natural.

Comment: You are right about the $k$. Using $n-k$ rather than $k$ is more natural in the context I'm considering but of course it makes no practical difference for individual $n$.

Comment: I only mentioned that because then you can take $n=\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I misunderstood your intention (see my comment above), if you take $n=\infty$ you get a Bernoulli convolution. See the paper [Sixty Years Of Bernoulli Convolutions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.5746) by Peres, Schlag and Solomyak which can also the last paper [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~solomyak/PREPRINTS/fractal.html).

Comment: The URL above doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I also get an error. I added a link to the paper on Boris Solomyak's homepage.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at that later when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

It is a finite distribution over numbers which aren't necessarily integers.  I wouldn't expect it to have a name.